# Change name of URI protocol handler in Windows

Tags: windows, registry, uri, protocols, handler

I have a project, [Search Deflector](https://github.com/spikespaz/search-deflector), that creates a URI protocol handler. When selecting "default apps by protocol" in Windows 10, the executable shows as `launcher.exe`. How can I change this to a friendly name?

Example:
[image: Screenshot]

I've followed the documentation for creating the protocol handler in the registry [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)).

I saw some other protocol handlers using `FriendlyTypeName`, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.